# Obtain user's home directory

Tags: go, home-directory

Is the following the best way of obtaining the running user's home directory? Or is there a specific function that I've ovelooked?

```
os.Getenv("HOME")
```

If the above is correct, does anyone happen to know whether this approach is guaranteed to work on non-Linux platforms, e.g. Windows?

Comment: `$HOME` is not *necessarily* the user's home directory.  For example, I can write `export HOME=/something/else` before launching your program.  Usually that means I *want* the program to treat `/something/else` as my home directory for some reason, and usually the program should accept that.  But if you really need the user's *actual* home directory, an environment variable won't necessarily give it to you.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Since go 1.12 the recommended way is:

```
package main
import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)
func main() {
    dirname, err := os.UserHomeDir()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal( err )
    }
    fmt.Println( dirname )
}
```

Old recommendation:

In go 1.0.3 ( probably earlier, too ) the following works:

```
package main
import (
    "os/user"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)
func main() {
    usr, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal( err )
    }
    fmt.Println( usr.HomeDir )
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or am I the only one where doing this on Windows takes several seconds?

Comment: It definitely seems instant on my Windows 7 64bit VM.

Comment: Be aware that as of go 1.1, "usr, err := user.Current()" will throw a "user: Current not implemented on darwin/amd64" error on osx.

Comment: It works on Mac OS 10.6.8 using Go versions as old as 1.0.3, 32- and 64-bit.

Comment: doesn't work when cross compiled
https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6376

Comment: Does not work in static builds because a error related with libc: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20468

Comment: Please DO NOT USE THIS, use ```os.UserHomeDir()``` instead, as it takes into consideration a user's environment variables and the XDG Base Directory Specification! See the answer below for details.

Comment: Answer doesn't compile on GO 1.13.8 Darwin64bit.  @ZacWolf's answer works, `os.UserHomeDir()`

Answer (score 88):

## os.UserHomeDir()

In go1.12+ you can use os.UserHomeDir()

```
home, err := os.UserHomeDir()
```

See https://golang.org/pkg/os/#UserHomeDir

That should work even without CGO enabled (i.e. `FROM scratch`) and without having to parse `/etc/passwd` or other such nonsense.

Comment: I hope enough people read-down this list because THIS is the function that should be used, as it takes into consideration a user's environment variables and the XDG Base Directory Specification!

Comment: This would even better if you use os.UserCacheDir() and os.UserConfigDir(); particularly for people with home directories on the likes of NFS or using roaming profiles etc.

Answer (score 24):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
)

func UserHomeDir() string {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        home := os.Getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.Getenv("HOMEPATH")
        if home == "" {
            home = os.Getenv("USERPROFILE")
        }
        return home
    }
    return os.Getenv("HOME")
}

func main() {
    dir := UserHomeDir()
    fmt.Println(dir)
}
```

Comment: This is same approach as Jeremy W Sherman which appears to be the only way at present. Many thanks.

Comment: This is the approach followed in viper util.go [userHomeDir()](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/80ab6657f9ec7e5761f6603320d3d58dfe6970f6/util.go#L144-L153)

Comment: In almost all cases where I see this used, this is *NOT* the right thing to do.  `USERPROFILE` is the root of the User's storage space on the system, but it is *NOT* the place where applications should be writing to outside of a save dialog prompt.  If you have application config, it should be written to `APPDATA` and if you have application cache (or large files that shouldn't sync over a network) it should be written to `LOCALAPPDATA` on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Similar answer to @peterSO but respects the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` path for linux.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
)

func userHomeDir() string {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        home := os.Getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.Getenv("HOMEPATH")
        if home == "" {
            home = os.Getenv("USERPROFILE")
        }
        return home
    } else if runtime.GOOS == "linux" {
        home := os.Getenv("XDG_CONFIG_HOME")
        if home != "" {
            return home
        }
    }
    return os.Getenv("HOME")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(userHomeDir())
}
```

Comment: Would love to see this answer updated to respect Windows too!  `APPDATA` for configuration and `LOCALAPPDATA` for large files.  For a general purpose "home" I recommend `LOCALAPPDATA` so by default application developers aren't wrecking corporate networks.  

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice, concise way to do it (if you're only running on a UNIX based system):

```
import (
  "os"
)

var home string = os.Getenv("HOME")
```

That just queries the $HOME environment variable.

--- Edit ---

I now see that this same method was suggested above. I'll leave this example here as a distilled solution.

Comment: 1. it's been suggested before, 2. it's not cross-platform, 3. the accepted answer already solves this problem in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the environment variable `USERPROFILE` or `HOMEPATH` under Windows. See [Recognized Environment Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104%28WS.10%29.aspx) (a more apropos documentation link would be welcomed).

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying, then, that HOME is not populated by Go for each platform (that it delegates directly into the O/S env vars) and I must check each platform's respective variable to identify the home directory?

Comment: I've had a look at the source and it appears HOME is not automatically populated. Seems there is (currently) no platform agnostic facility for obtaining the home directory.

Comment: @PaulRuane Since the platforms use different variables, just ignore the OS, check both variables, and go with whichever is populated. If both are defined, I would use `HOME`, since that probably means you're running under cygwin.

Comment: You should *NOT* use `USERPROFILE` or `HOMEPATH` on Windows in the vast majority of cases.  In almost all cases where devs use those, what they *should* be using is `APPDATA` or `LOCALAPPDATA` (depending on whether it is reasonable for the contents to sync over the network on login/logout).

Comment: Use ```os.UserHomeDir()``` instead, as it takes into consideration a user's environment variables and the XDG Base Directory Specification! See the answer below for details.

Answer (score 2):

go1.8rc2 has the go/build/defaultGOPATH function which gets the home directory.
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.8rc2/src/go/build/build.go#L260-L277

The following code is extracted from the defaultGOPATH function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
)

func UserHomeDir() string {
    env := "HOME"
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        env = "USERPROFILE"
    } else if runtime.GOOS == "plan9" {
        env = "home"
    }
    return os.Getenv(env)
}

func main() {
    dir := UserHomeDir()
    fmt.Println(dir)
}
```

Comment: Whilst the implementation of this Go function is interesting, this is a worse solution than using the standard library function described in the accepted answer. (And is the same approach as peterSO's answer from six years ago.)

Comment: This is not the right solution in *most cases*.  See comments on other answers, but the TL;DR is that `APPDATA` or `LOCALAPPDATA` is almost always the right choice, not `USERPROFILE`, on Windows.